# Javascriptの空白の消し方

Tags: javascript

・言語
JavaScript

・したいこと
日本語と英語が混じった文字列中の、日本語で挟まれた空白だけを除去したいです

・例
入力：田中 太郎 is Japanese boy.という 例文があります。
出力：田中太郎 is Japanese boy.という例文があります。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: お二人ともご回答ありがとうございます。
think49さんの方法で試した所、思ったような結果が得られました！
stackoverflowでの質問自体初めてでお礼の書き込み場所がここで正しいのかも分からないのですが、とにかくありがとうございました。非常に勉強になりました。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### 手順

1. [Unicode対応 文字コード表](http://ash.jp/code/unitbl21.htm)から「日本語」と「英語」に該当すると思う文字を選んで下さい。
2. 選んだ文字を正規表現の文字クラス(ex: `[a-z]`) で指定して下さい。
3. 2. で選んだ文字クラスで空白文字を挟み、`String.prototype.replace` で置換して下さい。

#### 注意点

「日 本 語」のような文字列に対し、`/日 本/` でマッチさせると `/本 語/` がマッチしなくなってしまう罠があります。
肯定先読み `(?=pattern)` を活用して対処して下さい。

#### スニペット

```js
function sample (string) {
  return String.prototype.replace.call(string, /([^\u0000-\u007F])\s+(?=[^\u0000-\u007F])/g, '$1');
}

console.log(sample('田中 太郎 is Japanese boy.'));  // 田中太郎 is Japanese boy.
console.log(sample('田 中 太 郎'));                 // 田中太郎
console.log(sample('"田中", "山田", \'佐藤\''));     // "田中", "山田", '佐藤'
```

#### spitson さんのコードの問題点

コメントを付ける権限がなかったのでここに書きますが、spitson さんのコードには次の問題があります。

- `[^\w.]` が半角スペースを含む為、 のような半角スペースの連続にもマッチします。
- 「,"'」等が「日本語」として扱われます。
- 「日 本 語」を「日本 語」に置換し、2つめの空白を取り除けません。

Re: 初心者 さん

Answer (score 3):

> 日本語と英語が混じった文字列中の、日本語で挟まれた空白だけを除去したいです

逆に解釈し、英数字だけで挟まれた空白以外を除去してみました。

```js
var str = '田中 太郎 is Japanese boy. 山田  花子 は Japanese girl.';

var str2 = str.replace(/([^\w.]) +([^\w.])/g, '$1$2');


console.log(str2);
```